# while select an image the file object comes with error and the mime type was "application/octet-stream" size is 0 but actual size is 30kb laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
 "file" => UploadedFile {#911

    -test: false
    -originalName: "smalllogo.png"
    -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
    -size: 0
    -error: 6
    #hashName: null
    path: ""
    filename: ""
    basename: ""
    pathname: ""
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/var/www/html/apartshub"
    aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    inode: false
    size: false
    perms: 00
    owner: false
    group: false
    type: false
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
```

when select an image and dd($request->file('file)) returns this i tried changes in php.ini file max_image_upload.but it works when i put this project into another server.php v 7.0,laravel 5.6

Comment: How is your file sent to the server ? HTML Form ? AJAX ? What is the type of transfer ? Can you post the client code ?

Comment: html form only i dont know why i cant eble to choose any images